# Upload multiple image files and display on the next page. PHP

Tags: php, html, forms, mpdf

I am attempting to upload multiple images at once, and then on submit display those images on the page. This is going to be used with mPDF.  I am using the examples in the manual at http://mpdf1.com/manual/index.php?tid=467

It has a text box and 1 image uploader, and displays what ever was in the text box and the image on the next page.  How can I convert this to use multiple images?

Page 1:

```
<?php
$html = '
<html>
<body>
<form action="example_userinput2.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
Enter text:
<br />
<textarea name="text" id="text"></textarea>
<br />
<label for="file">Choose Image to upload:</label> <input type="file" name="file" id="file" />
<br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
';
echo $html;
exit;
?>
```

Page 2: (also more specifically what I change the areas I marked ** **, after allowing multiple images.)

```
<?php

if (($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif" || $_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
& $_FILES["file"]["size"] < 20000)   {
// If the destination file already exists, it will be overwritten
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "../tmp/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
}
else {
echo "Invalid file";
}

$html ='
<html>
<body>
<div>'.$_POST['text'].'</div>
**<img src="' ."../tmp/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"].'" />**

<form action="example_userinput3.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<textarea style="display:none" name="text" id="text">'.$_POST['text'].'</textarea>
**<input type="hidden" name="filename" id="filename" value="'. $_FILES["file"]**["name"].'" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Create PDF file" />
</form>

</body>
</html>
';
echo $html;
exit;
?>
```

Page 3 goes to the mPDF generator so I can convert this to PDF for another project I have in mind.

Any help would be awesome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From php manual, to find here: http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.multiple.php

```
   <form action="example_userinput2.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      Send these files:<br />
      <input name="userfile[]" type="file" /><br />
      <input name="userfile[]" type="file" /><br />
      <input type="submit" value="Send files" />
    </form>
```

On page2, you can continue with a loop and handle those files at once:

```
foreach ($_FILES['array_of_files'] as $position => $file) {
    // should output array with indices name, type, tmp_name, error, size
    var_dump($file);
}
```

You can do the same as with one file in the loop

Comment: I know on page one I can do a <input type="file" name="file" id="file" multiple/>, and it will give me a box to select multiple images rather then having 10 different input file boxes.  

Its more of page two I am not sure how to re-code to take on multiple images.

Answer (score 0):

You can have multiple `<input type="file">` html elements set up on your page set up this way:

```
<input type="file" name="file[0]" />
<input type="file" name="file[1]" />
```

etc.

And then in PHP loop through them:

```
foreach($_FILES['file'] as $file){
    //refer to everything as $file instead of $_FILES['file']
}
```

That should be enough to get you started.